# Pagination with filtered queryset in ListView

Tags: python, django

I have a heir of ListView which looks like that:

```
class Index(ListView):

    model = Recipe
    paginate_by = 9

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return 'index_authenticated.html'
        return 'index_anonymous.html'

    def get_tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.all()
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = self.get_tags()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.getlist('filters'):
            qs = self.model.objects.filter(tags__name__in=self.request.GET.getlist('filters')).distinct()
            if qs:
                return qs
            return self.model.objects.all()
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

Removing any filter parameter will result in queryset getting shorter hence returning an error: `Invalid page (2): That page contains no results` Is there any way to handle such things beside creating custom pagination?